# How to append a hash to an array?

Tags: ruby

```
lines = ["title= flippers dippers track= 9", "title= beaner bounce house track= 3", "title= fruit jams live track= 12"]
songs_formatted = []
songs = {}

lines.each do |line|
    line =~ /title=\s?(.*)\s+t/ 
    title = "#$1".strip
    songs[:title] = title

    line =~ /track=\s?(.*)/
    track = "#$1".strip
    songs[:track] = track

    songs_formatted << songs
end

p songs_formatted

#=> [{:title=>"flippers dippers", :track=>"9"}]
#=> [{:title=>"beaner bounce house", :track=>"3"}, {:title=>"beaner bounce house", :track=>"3"}]
#=> [{:title=>"fruit jams live", :track=>"12"}, {:title=>"fruit jams live", :track=>"12"}, {:title=>"fruit jams live", :track=>"12"}]
```

**Each successive line is overwriting the line before it. Why isn't this just appending in order? Desired result is:**

```
songs_formatted = [{:title=>"flippers dippers", :track=>"9"}, {:title=>"beaner bounce house", :track=>"3"}, {:title=>"fruit jams live", :track=>"12"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to place the `songs` hash inside of the each loop. Working code:

```
lines = ["title= flippers dippers track= 9", "title= beaner bounce house track= 3", "title= fruit jams live track= 12"]
songs_formatted = []

lines.each do |line|
  songs = {} 

  line =~ /title=\s?(.*)\s+t/ 
  title = "#$1".strip
  songs[:title] = title

  line =~ /track=\s?(.*)/
  track = "#$1".strip
  songs[:track] = track

  songs_formatted << songs
end

p songs_formatted
```

Proper output:

```
#=> [{:title=>"flippers dippers", :track=>"9"}, {:title=>"beaner bounce house", :track=>"3"}, {:title=>"fruit jams live", :track=>"12"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want one output per line, you can use `map`. Also, you can extract both with one regex.

```
lines.map do |line|
  title, track = line.match(/title=\s?(.*?)\s*track=\s?(\d+)/)[1,2]
  {title: title, track: track}
end
```

This gives you the output you want.